# How to cache a specific folder?

Tags: cache

I have a folder that has a things in it that get frequently accessed. Some things get accessed a lot, and some don't. How can I set it up so that if something gets accessed enough times (i.e. 3 times) it gets moved to a higher, faster tier of storage (i.e. different disk), but still be accessible as if it's in the same directory?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to apply a Performance Enhancement before you've done Performance Analysis. "things"? "frequently accessed"? "accessed a lot"? "faster tier of storage"? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: A hard drive being the bottle neck of having files on it. There's an ssd and I want it to transfer to that so it has faster access. Instead of reading from the hard drive every time, it will read from the hard drive three times then move (not really move it, it would be in both locations) it to the ssd so then it would read from there for the next couple of hours, until it gets removed from the ssds and is only on the hard drives. It is a performance enhancement.